# Moving all cells into a new single column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file like
[Original File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4zio.png)

I want to transform all the cells that filled with information into a single column. Like
[To transform This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dEdK.png)
How to i do this ? 
I searched in internet about that i found just only transform cells in a single row to a single cell. But i couldn't find anything like this. Can you help me about that

Comment: You could use concatenate (&) or you could simply save as text or csv and then import into a single column.

Comment: Depending on your data set size this will be better suited for vba and not a formula.  The formula would most likely be an Array type formula and for large data sets this will cause a long calc time.

Comment: Three options, really - you can do it manually with Copy/Paste | Transpose, you can do it with an ugly formula that'll leave you with blank cells, or you can do it with VBA. VBA would likely be the easiest option, especially if this is something you'll need to do multiple times.

Comment: @Werf I think has the quickest solution. It's a quick loop: For each row, copy and transpose the data to a new sheet, column A. Then the next row, start at the end of that column, and resume transposing.

Comment: try this https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1172-excel-transpose-multiple-columns-into-one-column.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of code I keep around for this kind of job. It assumes that the values in each row are contiguous, that is there are no blank cells inside the data set. It also assumes that you're on the sheet that contains the data when you trigger it, and that you want the data to be placed on a new worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Columnise()
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngRow As Range, rngCol As Range
    Dim lCount As Long

    Set shtSource = ActiveSheet 'Or specify a sheet using Sheets(<name>)
    Set rngCol = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Set shtTarget = Sheets.Add 'Or specify a sheet using Sheets(<name>)

    'Define starting row for the data
    lCount = 1

    'Loop through each row
    For Each rngRow In rngCol
        'On each row, loop through all cells until a blank is encountered
        Do While rngRow.Value <> ""
            'Copy the value to the target
            shtTarget.Range("A" & lCount).Value = rngRow.Value
            'Move one space to the right
            Set rngRow = rngRow.Offset(0, 1)
            'Increment counter
            lCount = lCount + 1
        Loop
    Next rngRow

End Sub
```

You should end up with all the data in a single column on a new worksheet.

EDITED TO ADD: Since you mentioned your data does contain blank cells, it gets more complicated. We'll want to add a way to continue to the actual end of the data, rather than just looping until we hit a blank cell. We'll modify the Do While... condition to this:

```
Do While rngCell.Column <= Cells(rngCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This will loop until the end of the data in the row, then move on. Give it a shot and let us know.

Comment: it works on most cases but my excel contains empty cells, when this formula encounters an empty cell its moving another row not looking other cells right to the empty cells.

Comment: i figured out. i deleted "While rngRow.Value <> """ part of your code. probably its running all cells but it took under 1 min. so its enough for me. ty

Comment: now i reliase that when i deleted that part, its not moving other rows. probably imposible to do that without dimensioning.

Comment: Okay, if there are empty cells, we need a slightly more elaborate method of identifying when we've reached the end of a row. I've put in an alternative While... condition for you to try.

Comment: defining of rngCell is missing.

Edit : I define rngCell is like 
Dim rngCell 
it ended with an empty new sheet.